# Weak and strong topology on infinite dimensional spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory, normed-spaces

Is there a simple example to show that the weak and strong topology on an infinite-dimensional space do not need to coincide? I have several ideas using differences in the weak and strong convergence of probability measures (e.g. central limit theorem) but I'm looking for some $l^p$ example.

Comment: Have you looked at [the relevant Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology#Examples)?

Comment: yes I have, but even this example is on lebesgue spaces and uses another lemma. this wasn't my idea of simple. anyways if there is no straight-forward counter-example I will go this way.

Comment: For $1<p<\infty$, it's not hard to show that the sequence of unit vectors converges weakly but not strongly.

Answer (score 2):

In the weak topology of $X$, a basic  nhood of $0$ is given by a set of the form
$$
\{x\in X : |x_1^*(x)|,\ldots, |x_n^*(x)|<\epsilon \}
$$
for some $\epsilon>0$ and some finite set of elements $x_1^*,\ldots, x_n^*$ in $X^*$.

So a weakly open set containing $0$ contains  the set $I=\cap_{i=1}^n\text{ker}(x_i^*)$  for some finite set of elements $x_1^*,\ldots, x_n^*$ in $X^*$.  If $X$ is infinite dimensional, then $I$ is a subspace of $X$ of finite co-dimension.

It follows that there are strongly open sets that are not weakly open (such as the open unit ball of $X$).